# Copy to two local folders in WinSCP batch file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I have a batch file that I created that moves files from a UNIX (Solaris) server to a Windows XP computer. In the process it deletes the files off of the UNIX server.

What I'd like to do, is once the files have been transferred onto the "local" computer (where the WinSCP program is installed), I'd like it to copy some of the files (`RT*.dcm`) to another local (mapped network drive) folder.

I'd like to copy (only) the files that were put into the `C:\DICOM` folder into the `L:\dicomrt` folder.

Here's what I'm using for the initial portion:

```
# Created by Daniel E. Cronk to transfer images from the Pinnacle RT station to the LinAc computer.

# Comment out the next two lines to test
option batch on
option confirm off

# Connect - format: user:password@host
open ftp://username:password@hostname

# Change remote directory
cd /files/network/DICOM

# Change Local Directory
lcd C:\DICOM

# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary

# Download backup file to the local directory
get -delete RT*.dcm
get -delete CT*.dcm
get -delete MR*.dcm

# Disconnect
close

# Exit WinSCP
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no command for copying files local-to-local in WinSCP, as there no need for it, as you can use the [Windows `copy` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) (or the `xcopy`, if you prefer that).

If your WinSCP script is named `script.txt`, wrap it to a Windows batch file like:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /script=script.txt /log=winscp.log

copy C:\DICOM\RT*.dcm L:\dicomrt\
```

See a similar example [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload#scripting).

---

Or you can merge the two files into one like:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@hostname" ^
    "option batch on" ^
    "cd /files/network/DICOM" ^
    "lcd C:\DICOM" ^
    "get -delete RT*.dcm" ^
    "get -delete CT*.dcm" ^
    "get -delete MR*.dcm" ^
    "close" ^
    "exit"

copy C:\DICOM\RT*.dcm L:\dicomrt\
```

---

Note that the `option confirm off` command is not necessary in the latest versions of WinSCP. WinSCP also now defaults to the `option batch abort` (what may be more appropriate than yours `option batch on`).

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting

WinSCP also defaults to the binary mode, so the `option transfer binary` is not necessary either. And it is a deprecated syntax anyway, the correct syntax is the `get -transfer=binary -delete RT*.dcm`.

Comment: thanks, Martin. This worked exactly as I was hoping for. Appreciate it.